# I don't know how to use gRPC

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puon0.png)

`[szm@localhost helloworld]$ protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc-java=/home/szm/build/exe/java_plugin/protoc-gen-grpc-java --grpc-java_out=./src/main/java/ ./src/main/proto/helloWorld.proto`

I get `sayHelloGrpc.java`,but it has some trouble like that picture.

Answer (score 0):

`ServiceDescriptor` is a newer API. I expect you are using a newer protoc-gen-grpc-java version without also updating your dependency on the grpc runtime (grpc-core or grpc-all).

Comment: I used grpc-all 0.14.0
Problem has been solved. Thank you!